# How to fix 'Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted'

Tags: java, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make a post request to an http server, but when I try to get an input stream I get the error `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted`

I've already tried putting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in my manifest, as well as making a network security config and setting the android:targetSandboxVersion to 1

app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Server adress</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.packagename"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Logcat output

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:124) 
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 16):

Try using just

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

delete this 2

```
android:targetSandboxVersion="1"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

mine is working in any API just using `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: Where is this supposed to be located?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml @tazboy

Answer (score 5):

Create a file in your project

`res/xml/security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also if you have android:targetSandboxVersion in  then reduce it to 1

Comment: Edited my original question to make it clearer that I've already tried all of that

Comment: If above solution is not working, try changing your url's from HTTP to HTTPS it will also solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in your local machine make sure that you are requesting to **10.0.2.2** instead of **localhost** (this is very important)

Then make sure that your **AndroidManfest.xml** file has following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
        ... 
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

and your **network_security_config.xml** file must look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

or if you need to allow request to specific domains you could modify **network_security_config.xml** file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Both **network_security_config.xml** configurations works for me. I'm working on my local development enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do like this way it may be get run time error 
To Do easiest method;
go to android native project here you can see Properties click there then take AssemblyInfo.cs file then edit this part below

[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]

example below my code:-

```
 using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    using Android.App;

    // General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
    // set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
    // associated with an assembly.
    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ZATWEBO.Android")]
    [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ZATWEBO.Android")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
    [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
    [assembly: ComVisible(false)]

    // Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
    //
    //      Major Version
    //      Minor Version 
    //      Build Number
    //      Revision
    //
    // You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
    // by using the '*' as shown below:
    // [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

    // Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
    [assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
    [assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
    [assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
```

Note: this change only need android 9 Pie or higher versions

Answer (score 1):

I added the following code to the Android Manifest file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <base-config>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="system">
                </certificates>
            </trust-anchors>
        </base-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://YourURL/api/</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

Comment: what is this code used for <certificates src="system">!

Answer (score 0):

May be you made a mistake. Here is a correct format got it from another source.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
</domain-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

If you have android:targetSandboxVersion in  then reduce it to 1

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:targetSandboxVersion="1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem, airing my shame for posterity.

Accidentally put a url in `<domain includeSubdomains="true"></domain>` instead of a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by lowering the android version to 25 in And, the application works well on devices with android 9 and smaller.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the https request for both post and origin header. If you have one http request and the other is htps:// it won't work I had the same problem with the same error.